# `Resource doesn't exist` error deploying Function App container by GitHub Actions on infrastructure created via Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-functions, github-actions, azure-cli, azure-bicep

When deploying a Function App container by **GitHub Actions** via the `Azure/functions-container-action@v1` action, I get the error `Resource doesn't exist` even though the resource definitely exists. In my attempts it seems to me that the error occurs arbitrarily.

**Attempt 1**

I created an empty resource group via the Azure CLI. Via the Azure Portal I created manually a new Function App Container and Container Registry with all required dependencies. I created the service principal rights via the Azure CLI, as described in the tutorial. After that, I ran the GitHub Actions workflow.

Usually the deployment always worked, but today I had some attempts where the deployment failed. After that the deployment worked again, without changing anything.

**Attempt 2**

Like the first attempt, but here the resources are created by a Bicep file. After that, I ran the GitHub Actions workflow. In this case I always get the `Resource doesn't exist` error. Last week it worked once, since then I couldn’t get it to work anymore.

I've been trying to find the cause for the problem for days now and just can't find any solution. What am I missing?

The repository with all the code and scripts I used for the tests, you can find [here](https://github.com/akordowski/func-app-container).

Comment: Check out "Deployments" in the Resource Group on Azure Portal. It will provide you more context.

Comment: I'm curious, what is the reason of running Azure Function App in the Docker container?

Comment: Thank you for the hint with the deployments. Although I already compared the templates with a div tool and found nothing what could explain the error.

Comment: According to the docs running a Azure Function App in the Docker container is meant for cases the default service don't support. And I just wanted to know how to setup the pipeline ;)